# textFieldDidEndEditing - textfield limited value entry

Tags: swift, uitextfield

[image]

I am attempting to create a calculator that calculates results as `UITextField` values are changed. **There is no submit button** I figured `textFieldDidEndEditing`. Everything works with the exception of the `UITextField` where the user enters a value. The other fields on the form are `UIPickerView`s. It limits entry to 1 character in the free form `UITextField`.

```
self.mortgageAmount.delegate = self

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let selectedMortgageAmount = Double((mortgageAmount.text)!)
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here? "Everything works with the exception of the textfield where the user enters a value." What isn't working? Is the callback not being called? It should be called when the user ends editing only (as the name suggests) - is this what you want and observer?

Comment: The observer is calling, but when a value is entered in the text field it stops after the first character and will not allow any editing. My question is how do I figure out what's causing this?

Comment: I posted a screenshot. I app will not let me add more values or delete the 7. The only code that is controlling that cell is posted above.

Comment: That's odd. Does the same thing happen if you remove the delegate assignment? That should not be having the effect you're seeing. Can you do anything outside of the textfield? Do you have anything else running off of events - it looks like you're blocking the UI thread

Comment: This problem is fixed, thanks to the linked post below. I have the same on another UITextField know. This time the value will change, but only when I press the number 8. It increases the percentages value incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a submit button and want dynamic calculation while typing into the field, you need to use `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`, not `textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)`.

The former triggers each time any contents in the text field are about to change. The latter triggers only when the text field is done editing, either via a submit button or some other action, like scrolling the parent scroll view that is configured to end editing on scroll.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield